# R: class metadata location

Tags: r, r-s4

I have a question related to the creation of S4 classes in R.
The "setClass" function has a named attribute "where" which defines where the metadata
of the created class should be stored, according to the manual.

However, if I do the following

```
> en <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
> setClass("A", representation(x="numeric"), where=en)
[1] "A"
Warning message:
In getPackageName(where) :
     Created a package name, "2012-04-26 12:56:39", when none found
```

I can delete en using

```
> rm(en)
```

and am still able to use the class, e.g. with

```
> new("A", x=1)
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
[1] 1
```

Why is that?

Thanks in advance,

Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods package caches the class definition in `methods:::.classTable`, maybe for efficiency (class look-up) reasons. `removeClass("A", where=en)` would remove both the cached version and the definition (though generating a spurious warning).